# Local JavaScript Refused to execute script on several Flask Applications Suddenly

Tags: javascript, flask

I have several apps that I have been either maintaining or in the middle of developing. They run off of Flask and are deployed to Azure. Just the other day, all the apps started to produce the same overall issue from the console in Chrome on my local machine. I am getting the following:

[image]

Basically, what this is showing me is that all my local javascript is refusing to load.

At first, I thought this was isolated to my one app. Then I found it is like this for all of them. I then checked production, and it runs just fine. Then I tried different browsers. Chrome, Firefox, and Edge, it is showing the same thing. I then had another dev try it on their computer, which did not produce any error, although they are running off of Linux, while I am on windows 11.

The code running looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery.redirect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/aos.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/flatpickr.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jarallax.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jarallax-video.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jarallax-element.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/scrollMonitor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery.smartWizard.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/smooth-scroll.polyfills.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/prism.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/zoom.min.js"></script>
```

and like this:

```
auth = Blueprint(
"auth",
__name__,
template_folder="templates",
static_folder='static'
)
```

I am at a bit of a loss of why this is suddenly happening, and most confused about where to turn my attention in order to start to try and fix it. I thought maybe it was a chrome update that was cracking down on the http, since it was loading on my local machine, and that was why it worked in prod. But with all browsers doing it suddenly, that also does not make sense.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that on a Windows update, the register value was changed. I had to change back the Hkey_Classes_Root.js Content type from Text/plain to text/javascript:

[image]

This resolved the issue